# select all the options below the selected option in drill down select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selection, bootstrap-multiselect

How do I select all the options below the selected option

Example

```
<select multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

If I select `volvo` then all the options below `volvo`, i.e; `saab`, `opel` and `audi` need to be selected. Similarly, selecting `opel` should select `audi`  but not `volvo` and `saab`.

Comment: How have you tried to solve this yourself?

Comment: @amer it looks like you have a working solution below. If this is what you were looking for be sure to check it off as correct. You need to check off a working example so your questions aren't open ended

Comment: @CrazyJoeDavola Sorry I was actually trying to accomplish something else but the solution which was provided answers the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.nextAll()` to find all remaining options after the current one and set them to selected:

```
$("select").change(function(){
   $(this).find("option:selected").nextAll().prop("selected", true);      
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/k1cgvfa0/)